# Python Transpose/Stack multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Have a number of people that return responses to three questions.

These three questions are asked numerous times, the issue is new responses are recorded as new columns.

[image: Dataset]

Ideally the output would look similar to the below:

[image]

Have been exploring melt within pandas.

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['PersonID'], value_vars=['Q1', 'Q1_1', 'Q1_2', 'Q1_999' ] )
```

Looking for a more elegant solution then listing the value_vars Q1 to Q1_999

Comment: can you provide sample data, or is @Henry's data sufficient?

Comment: Henrys data is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little renaming to add a suffix to the base `stubnames`, we can the use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
# Add Suffix to base Q1 Q2 Q3
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],
                                ['Q1_0', 'Q2_0', 'Q3_0'])))

# Wide To Long
df = pd.wide_to_long(
    df,
    i='PersonID',
    stubnames=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],
    j='Attempt',
    sep='_'
).sort_index().reset_index()  # Order by PersonID instead of Attempt
```

---

Some sample Data and Ouptut:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PersonID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Q1': [232, 415, 152, 123, 234],
    'Q2': [2, 241, 5, 5, 5, ],
    'Q3': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
    'Q1_1': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    'Q2_1': [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    'Q3_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'Q1_2': [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    'Q2_2': [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
    'Q3_2': ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
})
```

Wide to long passing the results of rename directly:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(
    df.rename(columns=dict(zip(['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],
                               ['Q1_0', 'Q2_0', 'Q3_0']))),
    i='PersonID',
    stubnames=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],
    j='Attempt',
    sep='_'
).sort_index().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    PersonID  Attempt   Q1   Q2   Q3
0          1        0  232    2  Yes
1          1        1   10   15    a
2          1        2   20   25    f
3          2        0  415  241  Yes
4          2        1   11   16    b
5          2        2   21   26    g
6          3        0  152    5  Yes
7          3        1   12   17    c
8          3        2   22   27    h
9          4        0  123    5   No
10         4        1   13   18    d
11         4        2   23   28    i
12         5        0  234    5  Yes
13         5        1   14   19    e
14         5        2   24   29    j
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Henry;

Wonder what if the questions went from Q1 Q2 Q3 to past Q10, Q11; 
Would the stubnames Q1 use Q10 and Q11 as well?

Also for the separator; what if the separator was a space instead of an underscore

Comment: `sep=' '` to change the separator. For stubnames list them all -> `stubnames=['Q1', 'Q2', ... etc.]` Programmatically would be fine too `stubnames=[f'Q{i}' for i in range(1, 12)]`

Comment: Thanks Henry, that makes sense; what about if each header contained multiple underscores like 'Q1_1_1' 'Q1_2_2' (we wouldn't care about what happens after the second)

Comment: added a line to just remove everything after the last underscore df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', 1).str.get(0) :) thanks again for your help